# Incorrect string value: '\x92t get...' for column 'some_text' Error on an environment and not another

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Using a Spring **boot application:**

I have special characters inside a column, and when doing some actions on that table, I get this exception:

```
Incorrect string value: '\x92t get...' for column 'some_text' at row 1
```

I easily found that's its related to those special characters, more specifically this one: **'**, So I did:

```
ALTER TABLE `schema11`.`t11`
CHANGE COLUMN `preview_text` `some_text` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

The strange part is that the exception is thrown only on the server and not locally, while we have the same db dump.

How is it possible?

I have a `@Configuration` that does something like this:

```
ikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();    
dataSource.setConnectionInitSql("SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci");
dataSource.setDataSourceProperties(dataSourceProperties);
```

and

```
EntityManager em....
em.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Anyway, how could it happen on the server and not locally?

Comment: It would be nice to see a full stack trace. What exactly sql request is failed?

Comment: @SternK just doing a save to the entity, modifying another field only.

Comment: charset for that column/table/schema might be different in production to what you have in your local. I'd start by checking if they're different.

Comment: @DrunkenDaddy it was the same, changed both to be utf8mb4_bin anyway